# init observable properties on declaration (ts)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I didn't found answer on the web, so I hope you can help me with it.
I just began to use react+mobx+typescript.

Mobx configured to strict mode (enforceActions: 'always').
In the class I declare some observable properties and some of them I used to set value on declaration.

```
@observable 
let visitors: string[] = ['you'];
```

Now, because mobx configured to strict mode, I need to use action to mutate this observable.

So now, I do that in class constructor with wrapper "runInAction".

Do I right and what the best practices for it?